# Sveltekit's handleFetch in hooks only properly intercepts fetch call upon full page reload

Tags: svelte, fetch-api, sveltekit

I am using Sveltekit's `handleFetch` type to intercept any fetch request to set an Authorization header. It works as intended on full page reloads (e.g., by pressing F5 or navigating to the a page that uses authorization via typing it in the url bar).
However, it does not work via `a href`, `redirect` or on an initial load that does not refresh the entire page. Strangely enough, the code in `hooks.server.ts` is executed and the header is set properly as I can see the `console.log` statements.
Also, after a failed attempt (i.e. via a href or redirect), a full page reload is necessary for any other page to load properly again.

What am I doing wrong?

`hooks.server.ts`

```html
import {redirect, type HandleFetch } from "@sveltejs/kit"

export const handleFetch = (async ({ event, request, fetch }) => {
    if (request.url.startsWith('http://')) {
        request.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${event.cookies.get('access_token')}`)
    }
    // This logs to the console properly
    console.log("Modified fetch request")
    console.log(request.headers);

    return fetch(request);
}) satisfies HandleFetch;
```

`page.ts` in the route folder:

```html
import type { PageLoad } from './$types';

export const load: PageLoad = async ({ fetch, }) => {
    const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/fetch_accounts', {
        method: 'GET',
        credentials: 'include'
    });

    let content = await response.json();

    return { content };
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`handleFetch` only runs for fetches run on the server

(from the docs)

> This function allows you to modify (or replace) a fetch request that happens inside a load or action function that runs on the server (or during pre-rendering).

the `load` function in `+page.ts` runs on the server for the **first** request, but runs on the client for subsequent navigation (think of this as if once you are on the browser you are in a single page application).

A possible solution is to move the load to `+page.server.ts`, this load function will always runs on the server instead.
Another option is to proxy your request via a `+server.js` route.